# Derive Gini coefficient of lognormal distribution from definition

Tags: self-study, lognormal-distribution, integral, gini

The Gini coefficient of a lognormal distribution $\operatorname{Lognormal}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is $\operatorname{erf}(\sigma / 2)$, where $\operatorname{erf}$ is the error function. But how do I derive this expression from the formula for the Gini coefficient for a continuous distribution? That is, $$G = 1 - \frac{1}{\bar{x}} \int_{0}^{\infty} [1 - F(x)]^2 \mathop{d x},$$ where $\bar{x}$ is the mean of the distribution. (I'm in no way married to this line of attack. If there is a less convoluted way of arriving at the same result, then I'm all ears.)

I think that I can do the first few steps properly but in the end I just don't know how to tackle this beast of an integral. (The last step is perhaps thoughtless.)
\begin{align*}
G
&= 1 - \frac{1}{\bar{x}} \int_{0}^{\infty} (1 - F(x))^2 \mathop{d x}
\\ &= 1 - \frac{1}{\exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\right)} \int_{0}^{\infty} (1 - F(x))^2 \mathop{d x}
\\ &= 1 - \frac{1}{\exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\right)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(1 - \left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\ln x - \mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma}\right)\right)\right)^2 \mathop{d x}
\\ &= 1 - \frac{1}{\exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\right)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\ln x - \mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma}\right)\right)^2 \mathop{d x}
\\ &= 1 - \frac{1}{2^2 \exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\right)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(1 - \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\ln x - \mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma}\right)\right)^2 \mathop{d x}
\\ &= 1 - \frac{1}{2^2 \exp\left(\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2\right)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^\frac{\ln x - \mu}{\sqrt{2} \sigma} e^{- t^2} \mathop{d t}\right)^2 \mathop{d x}
\end{align*}

Comment: Is this self-study?

Comment: @EngrStudent Looks like it, does it not? :-) And, yes, it is self study but not for a class or anything like that. It is just something that I found interesting.

Comment: It is beautiful self study.  Some (trolls) will find a self-study question without a flag and downvote it.  I find that reprehensible.  I think the job of a teacher is to teach the fundamentals then teach the student how to teach themselves.  I think that watching a mature learner self-teach is a priceless opportunity for a student to learn how to self-teach.  I'm glad you did it, and I provided the comment to protect you from trools.  The integral of -t^2 can be attacked, sometimes, by relating it to a normal distribution which evaluates to 1.  I don't know if that works here.

Comment: I had asked this in a different form here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2714469/321264.